# INSERT INTO SELECT based on a dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I have a dataframe df and I want to to execute a query to insert into a table all the values from the dataframe. Basically I am trying to load as the following query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT *
FROM mydataframe
```

For that I have the following code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={' + driver + '} ;'
                            'Server=' + server + ';'
                            'UID=' + user + ';'
                            'PWD=' + pass + ';')

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = 'SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)

sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[new_date] SELECT * FROM :x'
cursor.execute(sql, x=df)
connection.commit()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using the counterpart of `read_sql` with [**`to_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)? Do not note the latter requires an SQLAlchemy connection (not raw DB-API one like `pyodbc`).

Comment: I've tried but I found a lot of issues like 'Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')'

Comment: See SQLAlchemy docs of MS SQL Server for setup of connection: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below my favourite solution, with UPSERT statement included.

```
df_columns = list(df)
columns = ','.join(df_columns)
values = 'VALUES({})'.format(','.join(['%s' for col in df_columns]))
update_list = ['{} = EXCLUDED.{}'.format(col, col) for col in df_columns]
update_str = ','.join(update_list)
insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) {} ON CONFLICT ([your_pkey_here]) DO UPDATE SET {}".format(table, columns, values, update_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues to connect pandas with SQL Server too. But I've get this solution to write my df:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?driver={5}'.format(username,password,server,port,bdName,driver))
pd.to_sql("TableName",con=engine,if_exists="append")
```

Comment: I really think that's better use pandas `to_sql()` than SQL `INSERT`statement to do this!

Comment: I've tried but I found a lot of issues like 'Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')'. I am putting for the driver name "SQL Server"

Comment: We cannot see your *driver* so you must adjust accordingly. See [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc) where spaces must be replaced by `+`. Maybe: `...driver=ODBC+{5}.format(..., driver.replace(' ', '+')`. Test with hard-coded values before dynamic variables.

Comment: Yes, @Parfait has the point. But I will edit my question to be a generic driver

Answer (score 2):

For raw DB-API insert query from Pandas, consider [`DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) with `executemany` and avoid any top layer `for` looping. However, explicit columns must be used in append query. Adjust below columns and qmark parameter placeholders to correspond to data frame columns.

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = '''INSERT INTO [dbo].[new_date] (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)
      '''

#  EXECUTE PARAMETERIZED QUERY
cursor.executemany(sql, df.to_numpy().tolist())   
conn.commit()
```

(And by the way, it is best practice generally in SQL queries to always explicitly reference columns and avoid [**`SELECT *`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451) for code readability, maintainability, and even performance.)

Answer (score 1):

cursor.execute doesnot accepts keyword arguments. One way of doing the insert can be using following below code snippet.

```
cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()])

# Insert DataFrame recrds one by one.
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO `[dbo].[new_date]` (`" +cols + "`) VALUES (" + "?,"*(len(row)-1) + "%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
```

here you are iterating through each row and then inserting it into the table.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers :) but I use the following code to solve my problem:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=database;UID=user;PWD=pass")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
query = query
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
df.to_sql(name='new_table',con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```